# Fractions inside the pieces

Tags: fractions

I am wondering if it is possible to create a pie chart with fractions instead of the default numbers inside the pie pieces (for one piece or for all pieces)? 
Thank you for your help.

Code:

```
\documentclass[fleqn,12pt, a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

%%I want 1/6 instead of 1 inside the pieces:
\pie[sum=auto]
{1/,1/,1/,1/,1/,1/}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EDITED to provide true `\frac` capability, all using the native keys provided by the `pgf-pie` package.  Three versions are shown:

1. `\frac`
2. `\displaystyle\frac`, and
3. `#1/#2`

First thing, is the fraction has to be provided in braces as `{a/b}`, so that `tikz` can evaluate it for calculating the pie-slice size.  Then, in order to get the label as a `\frac`, one uses `before number` and `after number` keys to basically unpack and evaluate the fraction not as a math calculation, but rather as math typesetting.

I figured out this solution by looking at the guts of the `pgf-pie` package and realized that the macros `\beforenumber` and `\afternumber` were part of the typesetting.  I, therefore, had to figure out how to define the keys to expand what I needed expanded, in order to evaluate `\beforenumber\p\afternumber` as, for example, `\frac{1}{6}`, when `\p` is defined as `{1/6}`.

The MWE:

```
\documentclass[fleqn,12pt, a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}

\def\myfrac#1{\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter%
  \expandafter\expandafter\myfracaux\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter#1}
\def\myfracaux#1/#2\relax{$\piestyle\frac{#1}{#2}$}
\def\piestyle{\textstyle}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
%%I want 1/6 instead of 1 inside the pieces:
\pie[sum=auto, before number=\myfrac, after number=\relax]
{{1/2}/,{3/16}/,{1/4}/,{1/16}/}
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\def\piestyle{\displaystyle}
\begin{tikzpicture}
%%I want 1/6 instead of 1 inside the pieces:
\pie[sum=auto, before number=\myfrac, after number=\relax]
{{1/6}/,{1/6}/,{1/6}/,{1/6}/,{1/6}/,{1/6}/}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
%%I want 1/6 instead of 1 inside the pieces:
\pie[sum=auto]
{{1/6}/,{1/6}/,{1/6}/,{1/6}/,{1/6}/,{1/6}/}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, it helped a lot. I tried to make the fraction looks more mathematically with "\frac{1}{2}", but it does not work with pgf-pie. Is there another way to label the pieces with \frac{}{}? Thank you for answering.

Comment: @KilianHof I figured it out, looking at the guts of the `pgf-pie` package

Answer (score 0):

The [wheelchart](https://ctan.org/pkg/wheelchart) package, which I wrote, can be used.

In the first example below, the numerator is the first variable (`\WCvarA`) and the denominator is the second variable (`\WCvarB`). The value is set with the key `value=\WCvarA/\WCvarB`. The fraction is displayed with the key `wheel data={$\frac{\WCvarA}{\WCvarB}$}`.

In the second example below, the numerator is the first variable (`\WCvarA`) and the denominator is the sum of all these values, given by `\WCtotalnum`. The value is the initial setting `value=\WCvarA`. The fraction is displayed with the key `wheel data`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{wheelchart}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\wheelchart[
  data=,
  pie,
  slices style=\WCvarC,
  value=\WCvarA/\WCvarB,
  wheel data={$\frac{\WCvarA}{\WCvarB}$}
]{%
  1/2/blue,
  3/16/cyan,
  1/4/yellow,
  1/16/orange%
}
\wheelchart[
  at={(7,0)},
  data=,
  pie,
  wheel data={$\frac{\WCvarA}{\WCtotalnum}$}
]{%
  1/blue,
  3/cyan,
  1/yellow,
  1/orange%
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```